Error when setting up ROS2 and VSCode
I'm trying to set up ROS2 and VSCode, following the steps in https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/How-To-Guides/Setup-ROS-2-with-VSCode-and-Docker-Container.html, but it gets stuck in two errors which I don't understand when "Dev Containers: Reopen in Container".

ERROR [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 2/4] RUN groupadd --gid 1  0.2s


Command failed: /usr/share/code/code /home/javierac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /home/javierac/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-a4d70a1a-1039-43ee-913c-feb5e30d89611723549545917 --workspace-folder /home/javierac/Documents/ros/prueba --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/javierac/Documents/ros/prueba --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/home/javierac/Documents/ros/prueba/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/javierac/Documents/ros/prueba/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root --include-configuration --include-merged-configuration

It tells me to modify locally the devcontainer.json, but don't know what's wrong.
My username is "javierac" and my workspace directory "/home/javierac/Documents/ros/prueba". My devcontainer.json is:
{
"name": "ROS 2 Development Container",
"privileged": true,
"remoteUser": "javierac",
"build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    "args": {
        "USERNAME": "javierac"
    }
},
"workspaceFolder": "/home/javierac/Documents/ros/prueba/",
"workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/home/javierac/Documents/ros/prueba/src,type=bind",
"customizations": {
    "vscode": {
        "extensions":[
            "ms-vscode.cpptools",
            "ms-vscode.cpptools-themes",
            "twxs.cmake",
            "donjayamanne.python-extension-pack",
            "eamodio.gitlens",
            "ms-iot.vscode-ros"
        ]
    }
},
"containerEnv": {
    "DISPLAY": "unix:0",
    "ROS_AUTOMATIC_DISCOVERY_RANGE": "LOCALHOST",
    "ROS_DOMAIN_ID": "42"
},
"runArgs": [
    "--net=host",
    "-e", "DISPLAY=${env:DISPLAY}"
],
"mounts": [
   "source=/tmp/.X11-unix,target=/tmp/.X11-unix,type=bind,consistency=cached",
    "source=/dev/dri,target=/dev/dri,type=bind,consistency=cached"
],
"postCreateCommand": "sudo rosdep update && sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y && sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/ws/"

My Dockerfile is:
FROM ros:jazzy
ARG USERNAME=USERNAME
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    #
    # [Optional] Add sudo support. Omit if you don't need to install software after connecting.
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
ENV SHELL /bin/bash

# ********************************************************
# * Anything else you want to do like clean up goes here *
# ********************************************************

# [Optional] Set the default user. Omit if you want to keep the default as root.
USER $USERNAME
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

Thanks in advance.

Welcome to Robotics, Javier Arambarri Calvo. It looks like the error is coming from your second RUN command in your Dockerfile, can you please edit your question to include (at least) that section? It could be any command included in the RUN command that's failing. At a glance I can see you're passing --gid 1, but the documentation says "GID must be unique," and that, "The default is to use the smallest ID value greater than or equal to GID_MIN and greater than every other group." Have you tried removing the --gid option?

updated! I think in the second line of Dockerfile $ is missing in "=USERNAME". It should be "=$USERNAME". However it keeps the error.

Here's an answer from SO that describes how to troubleshoot an issue like this. In part: "When one of the Dockerfile command fails, what you need to do is to look for the id of the preceding layer and run a shell in a container created from that id: docker run --rm -it <id_last_working_layer> bash -il Once in the container: try the command that failed, and reproduce the issue, then fix the command and test it, finally update your Dockerfile with the fixed command"
